# ASP.NET 3.5 Gridview layout for each product type in DB

Tags: gridview, product, autogeneratecolumn

I'm trying to create a simple CMS-likeb backend app that uses TreeView for categories and GridView for product display/editing.
The problem that I'm experiencing lies within the fact that there is a different table structure for each product type and only one page(GridView) that displays them.
That would not be so bad, as AutoGenerateColumns does a pretty nice job, except for one column that I need to display an image and in edit mode a button that activates a jquery script.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for your problem is to use a template field in your gridview  here is the link for the example [Adding Template Fields to a GridView Control](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/controls/addingtemplatefieldstoGridView.aspx)